# What is difference between these Wordpress filter hooks

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress plugin development. I have a doubt about below 3
 filter hooks.

- content_edit_pre
- content_filtered_edit_pre
- excerpt_edit_pre

  Please tell me the what the difference between these hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## content_edit_pre filter hook

The content_edit_pre filter hook is used to hook into the content of a post just before it is loaded to be edited. For example, if you included the following at the end of your functions file:

```
function test_of_content_edit_pre( $content, $post_id ) {
    return "Insert this before the content about to be edited ".$content;
}
add_filter( 'content_edit_pre', 'test_of_content_edit_pre', 10, 2 );
```

Then open a post to edit it, you would see that the text has been inserted before the post:

[image: content edit pre example]

## excerpt_edit_pre filter hook

The excerpt_edit_pre filter hook is very similar to content_edit_pre, except it is used to hook into excerpts (instead of posts) just before they are loaded to be edited. For example:

```
function test_of_excerpt_edit_pre( $content, $post_id ) {
    return "Add this to excerpt".$content;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_edit_pre', 'test_of_excerpt_edit_pre', 11, 2 );
```

Would result in this being shown in the excerpt:

[image: excerpt after filter hook]

## content_filtered_edit_pre filter hook

This one I am not sure about. I tested it out and it didn't seem to do anything. I will update my answer if I can find more information on this.

Comment: I have checked on the [wordpress stackexchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131451/when-does-a-function-assigned-to-the-content-filtered-edit-pre-filter-hook-fire) about the `'content_filtered_edit_pre'` filter hook.

Comment: Dear *wclear*, Your answer is very useful for me. Thanks for spending your valuable time for me.